# Condition check based on Pandas time duration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below given is the dataframe which has timestamp as index & resolution is 1 second. The dataframe has values for a whole day. There is a frequency column and a power column which was created using a condition on frequency column.

Condition: If frequency is less than 49.99 than power is -1000 and if it's more than 50.01 the power is 1000. There are instances when frequency deviates from the range of 49.99 - 50.01 in one direction for longer than 5 minutes.

| timestamp | frequency | Power[kW] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 49.92 | 1000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:01 | 49.96 | 1000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:02 | 50.01 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:03 | 50.13 | 1000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:04 | 50.02 | 1000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:05 | 49.97 | -1000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:06 | 49.90 | -1000 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:07 | 50.01 | 0 |

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

| timestamp | frequency | Power[kW] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:05:00 | 50.11 | 1000 |

Could someone please guide on how to add another condition on the power column that states that the values (1000 or -1000) in the power column cannot specifcially be 1000 or -1000 in continuation for more than 5 min.

I have tried using a rolling window. But the suggestions, I have came across apply .mean() or .sum() on the 5 mins window to decide for the specific row. Which ignores the fact that within this 5-minute interval, the frequency may deviate to either direction in the range.

The issue I am struggling with is to define that the power values shouldn't continuously be same for 5 mins. Highly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use sum or mean here instead you just need to check if all of the values are same or not which can be achieved using something like below (Im assuming you have created a rolling window with the power column

```
df['check'] = rolling_window.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sastaengineer ! I didn't create a rolling window with the power column. But now I tried  with the code 'rolling_window = df.rolling('300s')' and then used your code. But got an error that **'Rolling' object is not callable**. Could you please tell why this error is coming? Thanks!

Comment: please try - rolling_window = df['Power[kW]'].rolling(300). it will mark 1.0 across the row where 300s end, whenever it has caught constant values in span of 300 second.